# Eliminating border in project

Tags: qgis, shapefile, borders

My QGIS project consists of two adjacent Canadian NTS map sheets. Each sheet consists of multiple shape files. Each set of shape files has a border.  How do I eliminate the border?

[image]

Comment: Find the layer/s which has the border, then modify its/their symbology accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

Open layer properties and go to symbology. Click on your fill and select "no pen" as "stroke style":

[image]

*In case it is a line layer, simply disable it so it is not shown in your project or apply a transparent color to it.*

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it was a discrete shape file for each topo sheet that I found, of course, after posting this question. I was able to uncheck those two layers.